# Skype on MacOS keeps 600Mb caches, are these both deleteable?

Tags: macos, performance, disk-space, skype

Skype (7.56.0.776) on MacOS (10.10.5) keeps 600Mb in the two caches below, are these both deleteable without any negative effects? Can I prevent Skype doing this with any (Skype or MacOS) config setting? or do I just have to write a crude wrapper which monitors/purges these regularly? EDIT 1: wrt effect on performance, Skype keeps large disk caches, and crashes regularly, which may well lead to fragmentation.

```
348M    ~/Library/Caches/com.skype.skype/<username>/SKAvatarCache
213M    ~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/<username>/media_messaging/emo_cache_v2
```

Related to the second: [How do I prevent the Skype emoticon cache emo_cache_v2 directory from being populated with automatically downloaded images?](https://superuser.com/questions/1105986/how-do-i-prevent-the-emo-cache-v2-directory-from-being-populated-with-automatica)

Comment: Related to the second: [How do I prevent the Skype emoticon cache emo_cache_v2 directory from being populated with automatically downloaded images?](https://superuser.com/questions/1105986/how-do-i-prevent-the-emo-cache-v2-directory-from-being-populated-with-automatica)

Comment: (@patrix: I added precisely that URL and the answer on that question 10 hours ago. Then you rolled them back and pasted them here, as if they had come from you not me. Please do not rollback question details again. This is 2/2 questions this week.)

Comment: Questions get better answers if they are focused. In the current version of the question it's not clear whether you are asking about whether you can delete these two files, whether there is a way to prevent them from ever getting created, whether they are related to a (not explained) crash, whether they contribute to an (indescribed) disk fragmentation, or whether all of this this is part of a bigger problem (performance maybe) not even mentioned here.

Comment: Also, the link was added by an anonymous user and provided part of the answer to your issue. The site works better if answers are not included in the question text, that's why we regularly edit questions where the answer is edited into it.

Comment: @nohillside: The question is already plenty clear. Obviously if the cache contents were unnecessary then it is preferable to prevent the unnecessary stuff ever getting cached in the first place (if possible), else to script regular cleanup (e.g. after Skype finishes, or after boot). (FYI Skype was constantly caching and re-caching nearly a Gig of junk, so yes it was both a CPU and disk performance issue, on my machine. Whether fragmentation was or was not occurring was a tertiary issue which I couldn't diagnose. But Skype was definitely doing something grossly inefficient with its caches.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to delete these files, but there's no "harm" if you do.

- The `SKAvatarCache` holds thumbnails of your contacts for quick access without downloading each and every time from the Internet
- The `media_messaging/emo_cache_v2` holds the animated emoticons for faster rendering.

You can delete, but these files will be recreated when you view and/or message with contacts.  It's nothing that should be of concern that would require periodic maintenance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64998/discussion-on-answer-by-allan-skype-on-macos-keeps-600mb-caches-are-these-both).